# Small text on Google Chrome Dev browser mobile mode

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

**Why my browser mobile mode look like this?**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJsN5.png

I have tried many time but it looks small. I also had some problems in Google Chrome main browser. So I tried Google Chrome Dev here I got this problem. I use Ubuntu(Linux) as my operating system.

Comment: You problem will be better described if you also mention what you think it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

It may be obvious, but did you add a meta viewport tag to the site, like

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Otherwise we're probably going to need to see some code.